# How can I see what is in my smartstore soups?

Tags: android, eclipse, salesforce, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm building an android hybrid_local app with the Salesforce Mobile SDK that stores data in the smartstore. It seems to be inserted according to my log messages but when I query it, I don't get results back (or I get array.length = 0). So I'm assuming my query is wrong or the data wasn't inserted after all.

I'm using genymotion as an emulator and eclipse to launch the app. What do I have to use to be able to see the smartstore soups en entries in eclipse or some other software? Do I need to install an android app on my emulator?

I tried using "com.questoid.sqlitemanager_1.0.0.jar" but when I try to open the database file I get an error. Is that because data is encrypted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Mobilesdk 2.3 then you can see in browser by using

sfsmartstore.showInspector();

Have you tried above?

-Manish Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce's Smartstore library encrypts the database, hence you are not able to see any table or records inserted. In order to view the records inserted you need to retrieve the records by query. Use the standard methods of Smartstore library to retrieve the data from Soup.